# SQL connection works in VBA but not in Python

Tags: python, sql, vba

I have a code in VBA that reads in from a SQL server whose parameters are set as follows.

```
Global Const my_db = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=my_server;Initial Catalog=my_catalog;UID=user;PWD=opensesame;"
```

However, translating into Python as such didn't work for me:

```
import _mysql
db=_mysql.connect(host="my_server",user="user",passwd="opensesame",db="my_db")
```

The error I received is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\db_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    db=_mysql.connect(host="my_server",user="user",passwd="opensesame",db="my_db")
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my_server' (10061)")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a server called `my_server` you are trying to connect to ? (I understand you might have a different name, but `my_server` could be an example). If not, you probably mean `localhost` ?

Comment: yes, there is. The VBA code works without errors and I am able to query from it. I tried localhost and I received the same error...

Comment: Can you log in MySQL database through MySQL CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your SQL server is MS SQL server. Your VBA script connects to SQL server on port 1433.
Python script is trying to connect to MySQL server on port 3306 (default port of MySQL).

Try this:

import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=my_server;Initial Catalog=my_catalog;UID=user;PWD=opensesame'